# how to change the datepicker date based on first date picker in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, onchange

i have two date picker

i need to set add condition based on
first date picker

> if first  date picker selected current date then should be
>
> **second date picker will select after next date of selected in date picker - 1**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>

<input type="text" id="datepicker2"/>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
    minDate:0,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });

});

$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });

});
```

how i can do in jquery??

[Datepicker - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyrMG.png)

Comment: ___"second date picker show only next of selected in date picker -1"___ can you explain little more

Comment: in first date picker i have selected  
05-04-2019

then the second date picker will 
only show after 05-04-2019

Comment: `$(function() {` is a document ready event handler.  You only need one of these and can wrap both in that one instead of two.  Your question would be much clearer if you reference exactly which datepicker or tagged your question for example with jQuery UI if that is the one in use.  It would also help if you create complete, functioning snippets within your question.

Comment: Did any of these answers resolve your question?  IF so please mark that one as such by clicking the check mark to the left of that answer.  If not please add more detail in your question or a comment on each as to why it does not answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set an [`onSelect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) handler to the first datepicker, within the handler update [`minDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) [option](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option) of the second datepicker. Where use [`getDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) method to get the selected Date object.

```js
$(function() {
  let $dt1 = $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    // attach handler
    onSelect: function(dateString, instance) {
      // update minDate option of second datepicker
      // create a Date instance using datepicker instance
      // where increment the day value
      // $dt2.datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(instance.selectedYear, instance.selectedMonth, ++instance.selectedDay));

      // or you can get Date from jQuery object
      // or get jquery instance from instance
      // like : instance.input or $("#datepicker1")

      let date = $dt1.datepicker('getDate');
      // or let date = instance.input.datepicker('getDate');

      // increment day
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)

      $dt2.datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
      // to set min date as datepickers 1 value simply use
      // $dt2.datepicker('option', 'minDate', dateString );

      // incrementing day from a customized data string is hard that's the reason for using datepicker instance
    }
  });

  // cache the reference of input element
  var $dt2 = $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker1" />

<input type="text" id="datepicker2" />
```

Comment: how change the second date picker minDate based on
first date picker is next date

Comment: @prabhakaran7 : wait

Comment: superb can you plzz how this line works
$dt2.datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(instance.selectedYear, instance.selectedMonth, ++instance.selectedDay))

Comment: @prabhakaran7 : second argument in `onSelect` callbavk refers to datepicker instance object which holds values as property..... not minDate opyion accepts Date object as value so I'm creating a Date object instance by passing year, month and  day where day value is just incremented(++day) and passed to set next day

Comment: Why a new date and all that detail instead of just using the value of the first selector?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: please read the commented lines... He needs mindate as selected date + 1day..... That's it :)

Comment: Makes sense with that explanation of how you interpreted the question.  Hopefully the OP will begin to get better at clarity because as of today only 2 of 9 questions even have answers which IMHO is due in part to the clarity or specifically lack of therein.

Comment: Note also that the LACK of the original documentation where it does not even mention ANY events in part leads to these questions: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss : alternate way is to generate date from the datestring(+1day with the selected customized date).... While comparing I feels this one better

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss :  updated with documented method ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191265/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-mark-schultheiss).

Answer (score 1):

I would also consider keeping the second (dependent) `datepicker` disabled until the first has a value to better force the relationship.  I added a `data-dependent` to avoid hard coding but that is choice only.

Here I used the `onSelect` but it could be another event if desired.

I also fixed the ID you had in your selector for the first element.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function(date, datepicker) {
      let dependent= $(this).data('dependent');
      let thisDate = $(this).val();
      $(dependent).datepicker("option", "minDate", thisDate);
      $(dependent).datepicker('refresh');
    }
  });
  $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker" data-dependent="#datepicker2" />
<input type="text" id="datepicker2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

On selection of your first date just set -

```
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ minDate: <selected date from 1>});
```

e.g.

`$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date('05/05/2019')});` this will only show dates after 5th May 2019

Comment: I love this, but how did you get the 1st date value ?

Comment: You can bind onchange event to datepicker1.

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateMin = new Date(<?= date('Y,n,d', mktime(0,0,0,date('n')-1, date('d'), date('y'))); ?>);
let dateFinish = new Date(<?= date('Y,n,d', mktime(0,0,0,date('n')-1, date('d')+7, date('y'))); ?>);

$('#date-start').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    minDate: dateMin,
    maxDate: dateFinish
});
$('#date-finish').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    minDate: dateMin
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call a function in which you define both your datepickers like so:

```
function reinitialize()
{
  $("#datepicker1").datepicker('destroy');
  $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
    onSelect: reinitialize,
    defaultDate: new Date($("#datepicker1").val())
  });
  $("#datepicker2").datepicker('destroy');
  $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
    minDate: new Date($("#datepicker1").val()), // use min date
    defaultDate: new Date($("#datepicker2").val())
  });
}
```

Comment: Would a `refresh` be better here in the function instead of a `destroy`? http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-refresh  Perhaps add the initial instantiation of the `datepicker` as a part of this, outside that function.

Comment: Would this function not also remove the state of the original datepicker as well since it is destroyed when it receives the select event?